# How to create data types dynamically depending on the input

Tags: haskell, dynamic, custom-data-type

---

### Update for my original problems

Well, maybe I didn't describe my problem completely before. Sorry for all! The following is the real problem:

I have a txt file containing patent data, such as:

> 1/1523    DWPI
>
> AP      - JP29446999A 19991015
>
> PN      - JP2000188399  A       20000704    DW200044
>             JP4568930B2   B2      20101027    DW201071
>
> AN      - 2000495116
>
> PA      - (NPDE  ) DENSO CORP
>
> PR      - JP1998000295406   19981016
>
> MC      - U11-C18A3,U12-D02A
>
> OPD     - 1998.10.16
>
> ICAI    - H01L29/12,H01L29/78,H01L21/265,H01L21/336
>
> TI      - Planar type metal oxide semiconductor field effect transistor
>
> AB      - <-contents eliminated for simplicity->
>
> CPY     - NPDE
>
> FN      - JP2000188399

There are 1523 items with the similar format. I want to analyze the patent data, so I have to parse the data. I have defined the data type for every field, such as:

data AP = AP String Day String

```
data PN = PN String Day String

data AN = AN String

data PD = PD day

....  -- many other data types are not shown just for simplicity.
```

Now I have written the parser for every field with `megaparsec`, such as `apField`, `pnField`, `anField`, etc.

However, not every record has the same field, for example, the 2nd item may only contain fields of AP, PN, PA, PR, OPD, TI, AB, CPY and FN, with AN, MC, and ICAI missing. Besides, someone may be interested in different fields, and 
he just exports the txt file containing records only with fields of AP, PN, PA, OPD and CPY.

Now I want to write a generic code, which can parse the records with fields people are interested in, and write the parsing result into a `SQLite` database.

For example, if I want to parse records with fields of AP, PN, PA, OPD and CPY, I can construct a record parser according to the input, such as `toParser "ap,pn,pa,opd,cpy"`, or `toParser "ap,pa,cpy"`, which I have figured out. The parsed result should be `Record AP PN PA OPD CPY` or `Record AP PA CPY` respectively. Then I'd like to write the parsed results into a database. Since every record in the data corresponds to a `Record` data type, and the record to be parsed may be different, **I have to construct a `Record` data type with different fields depending on the user's input**. This is the problem that I have met.

I can work around it by defining all the field data types as `data Field = Field [String]` and the record as `data Record = Record [Field]`. However, I want more control over data type, such as a day as a `Day` type, and id number as a `Int` type.

If constructing `Record` data type with different fields depending on the input is impossible, maybe there are other ways to solve my problem. I appreciate any advices! And sorry for the long description of my problem and my ambiguous descriptions for my problem before!

Comment: Why would you want such a record? How would you use it?

Comment: Types don't _exist_ at runtime.

Comment: This is not possible, because types definitions are used at compile time, and removed as part of compilation.  There is probably a way to approach your actual problem, but it's not clear from your question what that problem is.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Even if you could create a type at runtime, you couldn't write a function that uses that type. It looks more like you want a sum type `T`  and `Record [T]`.

Comment: There are several projects for creating dynamic projections. You will need to be creative in your searches though, since Youtube searches are really, really, really bad. The one video I saw on Youtube was attempting to address the types of projections you get from SQL queries.

Comment: There are some ways something which may match your description. It would however be much more clear it you outline how are you gong to utilize such unknown at compilation type.

Comment: *However, I want more control over data type, such as a day as a Day type, and id number as a Int type.* - That requires a heterogenous list, or a simulation of thereof. An alternate solution is to make specific Field constructors that hold specific typed values.

Comment: Can you come up with a much smaller version of your problem (fewer types) that you can explain in much more detail? The sample text file you've presented looks like gibberish to me; it's not at all clear how it corresponds to the problem description. Please also explain in some detail a few of the operations you wish to support.

Comment: Thanks for all the helps! Using different fields to construct a `sum type` just solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I got your question right, no you can't write a single function which returns different data types depending on the input. However what you *can* do is write a function that returns a single data type that can be constructed in different ways depending on input.. i.e. like:

```
data PatentRecord = PN String Day String
                  | AN String
                  | PD day
```

so now you can write a function `parseRecord :: String -> Maybe PatentRecord` for example which parses your input and depending on what it matches returns a `PatentRecord` built using the `PN` constructor, or the `AN` constructor, etc...

PS: Implementation Tip: use rather an `Either SomeErrorType` instead of `Maybe` to provide richer information upon parsing errors ;-)